# Extract Hours from DateTime Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have a Pandas Series of DateTime

```
>> s
0             NaT
3        23:00:42
26            NaT
53       23:58:58
89       01:06:27
           ...   
20215         NaT
20217         NaT
20239    23:28:38
20246         NaT
20270         NaT
```

I first drop the NaT using:

```
s.dropna()
3        23:00:42
53       23:58:58
89       01:06:27
97       01:18:36
195      05:43:07
           ...   
20132    19:21:20
20141    20:08:01
20152    20:21:01
20199    22:25:50
20239    23:28:38
```

Now I try to get the hours from the series but not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is `print (s.dtype) ?`

Comment: dtype: object . Also if I access using values I get an array of datetime objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use if `s` is `Series` convert values to datetimes and then extract hours:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str)).dt.hour
```

Or get first 2 values and convert to  floats:

```
s = s.str[:2].astype(float)
```

If working with column:

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].astype(str)).dt.hour
```

Or:

```
df['hour'] = df['col'].str[:2].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s['hour'] = s['time'].apply(lambda x: x[3:5])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches. I would do it like this:

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(x).hour for x in s)
```

Comment: Hmmm, it is loop, slow in pandas, better use vectorized functions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. Will keep in mind.